# expected unqualified-id before '{' token Error with templates

Tags: c++, templates, avr, atmel

I am currently trying to integrate a library (IsoAgLib) into my CPP project. I am not deeply experienced with CPP. The error I am getting is: "expected unqualified-id before '{' token". I believe it has something to do with templates as I have come across other similar issues. It might also have something to do with the abs function call. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I am leaving out code after the template, the file is quite large

Error   45  expected unqualified-id before '{' token
Error   47  expected unqualified-id before ')' token
Error   46  expected ')' before '{' token

all of these errors occur on line 31 which is "template  inline T abs(const T& val)" (I left commenting out at the beginning)

```
#ifndef UTIL_FUNCS_H
#define UTIL_FUNCS_H

#include <IsoAgLib/isoaglib_config.h>
#ifdef USE_DATASTREAMS_IO
class StreamInput_c;
#endif
#include <cstdlib>  // Include before vector or else CNAMESPACE stuff is screwed up for Tasking
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#ifdef USE_VT_UNICODE_SUPPORT
#include <string>
#endif

// Begin Namespace __IsoAgLib
namespace __IsoAgLib
{
  template <class T> inline T abs(const T& val)
  {
    return (val < 0) ? (-val) : val;
  }

} // end of namespace __IsoAgLib
#endif
```

Comment: maybe add a } at the end of the file to close namespace statement

Comment: Just so you know, names with two underscores or beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation (compiler) and should not be used.

Comment: @Nagasaki The file is actually much larger so the namespace is closed off.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post a short, self contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @user2291405 The error you mention should have told you *what line* that error occurs on.  Can you add that to your question?

Comment: Is your code complete? Where does the error occurs?

Comment: Is there a `#define abs` somewhere in your header files?

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield yes there is a #define abs macro in one of the header files, I tried commenting it out and hoped it would use the one in <cstdlib> no such luck. I get "implicit declaration of function Abs" error from another file

Comment: Then that's the problem. Macros respect nothing. Wherever you write `abs`, the preprocessor immediately replaces it with the macro text without even giving the compiler a chance to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some systems abs() and others such as min() and max() are implemented as preprocessor macros. To see if that's the case for you, add the line

```
#undef abs
```

after this line:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

The preprocessor has no respect for namespaces and will blindly substitute its definition of abs into your source code before it's fed to the compiler even if the result is syntactic chaos.